# Are dead zone function and saturation function lipschitz functions?

Tags: calculus, analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let

- $sat_{\bar{u}}(u) = sign(u)\min({|u|, \bar{u}}), \bar{u}>0$, be a saclar function from $\Bbb{R}$  to $[-\bar{u}, \bar{u} ]$.
- $dz_{\bar{u}}(u) = sign(u)\max({0, |u|-\bar{u}}), \bar{u}>0$, be a saclar function from $\Bbb{R}$  to $\Bbb{R}$.

I want to prove that $sat_{\bar{u}}$ and $dz_{\bar{u}}$ are globally 1-Lipscitz functions.

Can anyone please help me out here?

Thanks a lot